# How to interpret behaviour of my cat during brushing

Tags: cats, behavior, grooming

This is this time of year when my cats decided they need a new fur for the coming season (and being very non-eco friendly they want natural). Rogue started to shed a lot and as there was also a bit of shed fur left in fur I started brushing as I was afraid of hairballs (as far as I understand those are not healthiest for her).

However she often starts to kick/slightly bite me/brush when I'm doing it or walks away. I never heard her cry however, she often purrs and the body language seems fine (tail up/question mark/ears to the front). Am I correct in assumption that it feels for her like combination of playing with her sister (play scratch/play bites) and petting so she responds in kind or is it hurting her?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your assumptions sound correct to me.

It would most likely result in at least some growling or more aggressive behavior if your cat overlords wouldn't condone such practices employed by thy hooman slave.

Besides that, hairballs are completely normal and won't harm otherwise healthy cats.

Comment: For what it's worth, one of mine, after being combed for a while, insists upon grabbing the comb and grooming it in turn. I interpret that as something between "this is nice, thank you" and "done now" and "mine" ... If we understood them perfectly, they wouldn't be cats.

Comment: @keshlam my cat insists on nipping at the brush. Not that he has the attention span for me to brush him for more than a few quick strokes along his flank before he gets bored and saunters off.